# Query giving double result instead of single

Tags: sql, laravel, search, filter

I have two tables: `products` and `current_product_attribute_values`

I have tried a join query to filter them as per attribute selected by the `user` but when I try this with an additional condition it gives me 2 results instead of one it is including the first one which is not matching as per query:

```
select * from `products` inner join `current_product_attribute_values` on `products`.`id` = `current_product_attribute_values`.`product_id` where `current_product_attribute_values`.`attribute_id` = ? or `current_product_attribute_values`.`attribute_value_id` = ? and `current_product_attribute_values`.`attribute_id` = ? or `current_product_attribute_values`.`attribute_value_id` = ? and `product_name` LIKE ?
```

here is my laravel Controller code :

```
 $all = Input::all();  

 $q = Input::get('search_text');

 $att_val = Input::get('attribute_value');

 $subcat = Input::get('subcat_id');

 $subcat_name = DB::table('subcategories')->where('id', $subcat)->value('subcategory_name');

 $brandname = DB::table('brands')->where('subcat_id', $subcat)->value('brand_name');

 $brand_id = DB::table('brands')->where('subcat_id', $subcat)->value('id');

 $product_count = DB::table('products')->where('brand_id', $brand_id)->count();

            if ($q != "") {

// getting multiple same name params    

                $query = DB::table('products');

                $query->join('current_product_attribute_values', 'products.id', '=', 'current_product_attribute_values.product_id');

                $j = 0;

                foreach ($all as $key => $values) {

                    //echo 'my current get key is :  ' . urldecode($key). '<br>';    

                    if ($key == $name[$j]) {

                        $query->where('current_product_attribute_values.attribute_id', '=', $att_id_value[$j]);
                        echo'<br>';
                        print_r($query->toSql());
                        echo'<br>';
                        //echo '<br> key matched and have some value : <br>';
                        //echo count($values);
                        if (count($values) >= 1) {

                             //echo '<br> it has array inside <br>';

                            foreach ($values as $val) {
                                //   or waali query in same attribute                                  
                                echo'<br>';
                                $query->orwhere('current_product_attribute_values.attribute_value_id', '=', $val);

                                print_r($query->toSql());
                                echo'<br>';
                            }
                        }

                        $j++;
                    }
                }

$records = $query->toSql();

                $query->where('product_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%');

                $records = $query->toSql();

print_r($records);

                $products = $query->paginate(10)->setPath('');

                $pagination = $products->appends(array(
                    'q' => Input::get('q')
                ));

                if (count($products) > 0) {

                    $filters = DB::table('product_attributes')->where('subcategory_id', $subcat)->get(['attribute_title']);
                } else {

                    $filters = array();
                }

                $categories = categories::where('add_to_menu', 1)->with('subcategories')->with('brands')->get();

                $categoryhome = categories::where('add_to_menu', 1)->with('subcategories')->get();

                return view('searchfilter')
                                ->with('productsdata', $products)
                                ->with('filtersdata', $filters)
                                ->with('categories', $categories)
                                ->with('categorieshome', $categoryhome)
                                ->with('subcat_name', $subcat_name)
                                ->with('subcat_id', $subcat)
                                ->with('brandname', $brandname)
                                ->with('product_count', $product_count)
                                ->with('querytext', $q);
            }
            return 'No Details found. Try to search again !';
```

[image: CurrentProduct_attributes_values table][image: Products Table]

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: thanks for your reply Gordon Linoff updating my question .....

Comment: can you provide an example of the  desired result?

Answer (score 0):

its easier if you use raw sql as calling db select function. ex:

```
$query=DB::select("select * from `products` inner join `current_product_attribute_values` on `products`.`id` = `current_product_attribute_values`.`product_id` where `current_product_attribute_values`.`attribute_id` = ? or `current_product_attribute_values`.`attribute_value_id` = ? and `current_product_attribute_values`.`attribute_id` = ? or `current_product_attribute_values`.`attribute_value_id` = ? and `product_name` LIKE ?
");
```

indeed you can concat vars in raw sql if you need to, ex:

```
$queryBrands = "select id from brands where subcat_id =".$subcat;
//echo $queryBrands
$queryBrands = DB::select($queryBrands);
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply ruff0 i used that too but the problem is my and condition not working as the AND work its is giving me all result like or did not checking for both conditions

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your tables, `product` table with `id` value **17** has *two* records in table `current_product_attribute_values` in column `product_id` (I assume this column is used as foreign key to `product` table).

With `select *`, you select *all* of the columns from *both* tables. So it would most likely cause your query to return multiple records.

My suggestions:

- Only select the columns you need. Avoid using `select *` in the long run, i.e. `select product.id, product.description, current_product_attribute_values.attribute_values ......`
- Make use of `GROUP BY`

Hope these helps.

Comment: thanks for ur reply cipley but here these similar records has different attributes so when I filter them like for example RAM 64GB and processor Demo3 then I just want the single result of every product having both things but in my case, it is giving me multiple differ record like or statement given

Comment: The problem is you used `select *`, so the records with different values will be shown in the result set as well. That's why you should only select the columns you want to be shown, and use `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT` as you need.